# Conflicting types error in C after using prototype

Tags: c, xcode, getline

I try to run an example code in K&R (p30) using Xcode. I got conflicting types error for 'getline' and when I call `getline`, I was informed that I should pass `3` arguments to it, instead of `2`. I'm confused.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 /* maximum input line length */

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print the longest input line */
int main()
{
    int len; /* current line length */
    int max; /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE]; /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE]; /* longest line saved here */

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line[MAXLINE], MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0) /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/* getline: read a line into s, return length */
int getline(char s[],int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: Because there is [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: Don't read K&R. It is ancient and you'll pick up tons of bad habits from it.

Answer (score 7):

Since K&R was written, POSIX has added a function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)
which has a different interface from the one in K&R:

```
ssize_t getline(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n, FILE *restrict stream);
```

The only reasonable way around it is to rename the function in the code copied from the book.

(It was a nuisance when it was added — I'd used a variant on the K&R code for 20+ years, but there's no point in fighting it.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your args should have the same name:

```
int getline(char line[], int maxline);
int getline(char s[],int lim)
```

Plus, as said above, getline is a func that already exists in stdio library.
You should rename your func like

```
int my_getline
```

or something.

Good luck !